# Is a sequence, which has each term bigger than each term of an unbounded monotonically increasing sequence, divergent?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I have two sequences of partial sums $$(S_k)_{k\in\mathbb{N}} \,\,\,\text{and}\,\,\, (T_k)_{k\in\mathbb{N}}$$.

I know that $\{T_k\}$ is the sequence of partial sums of an harmonic series, so that $$T_k = \sum_{n=1}^{k}\frac{1}{n}$$

I'm also given that $\{T_k\}$ is an unbounded monotonically increasing sequence, i.e. it diverges. Finally, I know that each term of $\{S_k\}$ is strictly bigger than each term of $\{T_k\}$.

Can I conclude that $\{S_k\}$ diverges? Clearly It seems like I can, as it cannot converge to a finite limit, or otherwise at a certain point, the terms of $\{S_k\}$ wouldn't be bigger than the terms of $\{T_k\}$.

This is my argument for an exercise, (of which I am not giving you the expression of $\{S_k\}$, although it is given), however the solutions of my lecturer say that I HAVE to prove that $\{S_k\}$  is also monotonically increasing and unbounded in order to prove that it diverges. But that is clearly not the case as I can prove it without it. In the solutions the lecturer says you have to use the expression of $\{S_k\}$ to show it is increasing and unbounded.

Do you think the lecturer missed this way of proving it or am I wrong somewhere?

Comment: I would think that you know that $S_k$ is monotonically increasing because each $S_k$ is larger than each $T_k$ and you know that $T_k$ is monotonically increasing.

Comment: I think your argument is wrong. $T_k$ might be monotonically increasing and increase towards a finite limit, call it $T$. Then $S_k$ could simply have each term bigger than $T$ and still not be monotonically increasing, indeed it could go up and down, as long as it is above $T$. But adding the condition of $T_k$ being unbounded, it should work, shouldn't it?

Comment: I see what you are saying. Yes, $S_k$ might not be strictly increasing, but it's general trend is upward. In a situation like this I prefer the Comparison Test, which does not require the series to be monotonically increasing.

Comment: Would you use the Comparison Test even if $S_k = \sum_{n=1}^{k}\frac{1}{n^s}$ for $s<1$?

Comment: You can, but there's also another test that is commonly called the P-test, which can be applied to that specific series as well to show it diverges

Answer (score 1):

You're right. However, perhaps the lecturer doesn't want you using the fact that $S_k\geq T_k$ for all $k$. You've mentioned the series in the comments. The exact same usual argument that shows that $T_k$ is unbounded shows that $S_k$ is unbounded, and it's obviously increasing. It can't hurt to appease the lecturer and do it their way.

Comment: true, however it looks to me that following the lecturer's way, I have to prove 2 more things, which I don't really need!

Comment: @Euler There's not much value in seeking the highest level of economy. Doing things you don't strictly need to do can give you an alternative perspective. Having two proofs of something is better than only having one.

Comment: okay, I understand. Thank you